# How to check at least one radio button is selected in a td tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<table>
    <tr><td>RNO.1</td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="att1" name="att1" value="P"/>Present 
    <input type="radio" id="att1" name="att1" value="A" />Absent 
    <input type="radio" id="att1" name="att1" value="L" />Leave
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>RNo.2</td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="att2" name="att2" value="P"/>Present 
    <input type="radio" id="att2" name="att2" value="A" />Absent 
    <input type="radio" id="att2" name="att2" value="L" />Leave
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>RNo.3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" id="att3" name="att3" value="P"/>Present 
    <input type="radio" id="att3" name="att3" value="A" />Absent 
    <input type="radio" id="att3" name="att3" value="L" />Leave
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to check at least one radio button is selected in each td using javascript also RNo's will increase i just put few. Please help me.

Comment: ID should not be duplicated

Comment: `table's` immediate child should be `tbody`.

Comment: It must have been very hard to ignore the suggestions of duplicate presented to you when you wrote the question. You really need to change the IDs too: `<input type="radio" id="P1" name="att1" value="P"/>Present 
    <input type="radio" id="A1" name="att1" value="A" />Absent 
    <input type="radio" id="L1" name="att1" value="L" />Leave`

Comment: Are you using `jQuery`? If so: `$('table td input:radio').is(':selected').length > 0`

Comment: It is not tagged jQuery, but a selection using querySelectorAll can be used for plain JS. @KennyThompson your code will not check each row, just all radios

Comment: id should not be same and name should be different for different td radio buttons. Also are you using vanilla js or jquery or angular or any other library / framework ?